# Laravel - what means Vanilla PHP

Tags: php, laravel

In the Laravel documentation, on route caption, at point where explain how to create csrf token, the doc says:

```
// Vanilla PHP
<?php echo csrf_field(); ?>

// Blade Template Syntax
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

What it mean for Vanilla PHP? Thank in advance! :)

Link to the doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-protection

Comment: maybe **raw**? It means PHP in the way you use it without any template engine in this case

Comment: @whoam i to think in this way, but i never heard before the Term Vanilla PHP

Comment: @Nick you right! Vanilla means Plain!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What it means is that you're echoing the method they've created in Vanilla PHP - thus, standard PHP. Below it, you'll see the `{{ csrf_field() }}` which is the Blade syntax provided with Laravel. It simply presents you with two ways to output the same thing - one in "Vanilla", and one with Blade!

Comment: Vanilla PHP means - Standard PHP?

Comment: @ArturMamedov Vanilla PHP simply means standard, pure, plan, original PHP without any framework or template system.

Comment: Yes now i understood, thanks to all guys!